# Understanding bridge pattern and Java streams

Tags: java, design-patterns, io, bridge

I'm reading GoF design patterns and trying to undersand the Bridge pattern. Now, consider the Java streams ([official documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html)).

They introduced two kind of streams: ***Node streams*** and ***Filter streams***. The latter uses ***Node streams*** to perform the actual writing to/ reading from another stream. So Node streams incapsulate low-level IO details. In the sense of GoF Bridge pattern, can Node Streams be considered as a bridge (`Implementor`) which are used by Filter streams?

If so, is it a good practice not to create a separate interface for a Bridge. For example:

```
public interface DataWriter{

    public void write(Object);
}
```

In my case, there might be two kind of implementatios: one that defines low-level IO details, and one that performs convertions, validation, etc. and uses underlying DataWriter to write data (to file system persistance store, Java `OutputStream`, etc.). Can I consider that the first one is a bridge and just write a JavaDoc for the interface in order to avoid creating another `DataWriterImplementor` interface?

Comment: I used the Bridge pattern exactly once twenty years ago and I've regretted it ever since. Don't feel you have to use every pattern in the book.

Comment: @EJP That's a good point, but doesn't it suit well for my situation? I mean, I could provide different implementors (`StreamWriterImplementor` and e.g. `DataBasePersistenceImplementor`). Isn't that a wrong approach?